# Expressing $I/J$ in terms of quotients of the larger ring

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring. Let $I\subseteq J$ be nonzero left ideals of $R$. Can the factor ring $I/J$ be expressed in terms of sums, quotients or submodules of rings of the form $R/K$, where $K$ is any left ideal of $R$?

Also, is $I/J$ is torsion? We get finitely generated for free because of Noetherian-ness, I believe.

Comment: First of all, for $I\subseteq J$, it's usually customary to write the quotient as $J/I$ rather than $I/J$. Secondly, what do you mean by torsion? Most sources only talk about torsion modules over a domain, but there *are* other definitions... Finally, what does being finitely generated have to do with being torsion? (I guess this depends on your definition of torsion.)

Answer (score 2):

> Can the factor ring $I/J$ be expressed in terms of sums, quotients or submodules of rings of the form $R/K$, where $K$ is any left ideal of $R$?

The most sensible correction to this I can see is

> Can the factor ring $J/I$ be expressed in terms of sums, quotients or submodules of modules of the form $R/K$, where $K$ is a left ideal of $R$?

Notice that I had to switch "rings" to "modules" because you required $K$ to be a left ideal, but $R/K$ won't be a ring unless it is a two-sided ideal.

In this interpretation, $J/I$ is a submodule of $R/I$.

It's unclear what definition of torsion you wanted, but you haven't clarified for over a year, so I'll give it a shot.

Certainly $J/I$ does not have to be a singular module, and it certainly might have a nonzero element with annihilator zero, so it would not be torsion in either of these senses.